# Mechanism for Identification Networkx Graphs saved in a database

Tags: database, python-3.x, pickle, networkx

I am using Networkx to generating graphs and saving some of them in a Postgresql database. When a graph is generated it has to be saved in the database but only if the graph meets one condition:

- There is no other graph similar to it already saved in the database.

In my database I have a table with two columns

1. The first one used to save the graph after it is pickled (binary data)
2. The second one has a hash which represents the graph (Char)

When I create a new graph I generate its hash based on the edges of the graph, then I check the hashes of the other graphs already saved in the database. If a graph with a similar hash already exits in my database then I don't store it, other wise it has to pickled then stored.

My question is, does anyone have a fast efficient alternative to my process, or is using this hash the only way to achieve my goal?

Just a small note, I use a hash and not the pickled graph because I am worried that two similar graphs might look different when they are pickled due to aspects that did not occur to my mind and just thought that using a hash would be fast and safe.